# How to get the value of a variable when I only have the variable's name as a string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a string passed through from the previous page which contains a companies name, let's say it's 'Apple'.

On this page I then want to access an object called 'Apple' to get details about it.

I have tried with template literals but doesn't seem to work.

`` `${companyName}`.map((item) ``

I'm using reactjs.

Comment: that other question doesn't help

Comment: It goes in good depth in how you'd get the result you want. It's also exactly the same thing you asked - you have a string, you want the variable with the same name. If it doesn't help, then you seem to have asked a different question but worded it the same as that one. Without knowing *what* is different, there is no way to know what the correct answer would be.

Comment: I got the answer I needed elsewhere in the end.